# JavaFX undecorated Window with shadow

Tags: javafx

I am trying to figure out, how to create an undecorated window with its regular shadow behaivor (like for all windows when using Windows).

I read several articles but non of them really worked.

As far as I understood, I have to create the main stage with some kind of padding. This stage has to have a transparent background. The actual content needs to be placed on some kind of other node.

So I took a stackpane for my root element and placed a vbox on it. The vbox should by the actual main stage area (I colored that area in green).

But I tried to use the StageStyle to transparent, I tried to fill out the stackpane with a transparent background but non of them worked. Also the shadow doesn't work as expected (I removed the shadow experiment in my example).

```
private void createPopup2() {
        StackPane stackePane = new StackPane();
        VBox rootPane = new VBox();
        rootPane.setStyle("-fx-background-color: green; -fx-border-color: black; -fx-border-width: 1px;");
        stackePane.getChildren().add(rootPane);
        stackePane.setPadding(new Insets(20, 20, 20, 20));
        Scene scene = new Scene(stackePane);
        final Stage stage = new Stage();
        stage.initStyle(StageStyle.TRANSPARENT);
        stage.setWidth(600);
        stage.setHeight(350);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.initModality(Modality.APPLICATION_MODAL);
        stage.show();
    }
```

I am quite confused and have no idea how to fix that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly I am not sure what type of shadow you are expecting. It will be helpful if you can provide the example for shadow you tried, so that we may know the actual issue.

Having said that, have you tired using -fx-effect on VBox.? The below code creates a shadow effect around the green box.

```
StackPane stackePane = new StackPane();
stackePane.setStyle("-fx-background-color:transparent");
VBox rootPane = new VBox();
rootPane.setStyle("-fx-background-color: green; -fx-border-color: black; -fx-border-width: 1px;-fx-effect: dropshadow(gaussian, rgba(0, 0, 0, .75), 20, 0.19, 0, 0);");
stackePane.getChildren().add(rootPane);
stackePane.setPadding(new Insets(20, 20, 20, 20));
Scene scene = new Scene(stackePane, Color.TRANSPARENT);
final Stage stg = new Stage();
stg.initStyle(StageStyle.TRANSPARENT);
stg.setWidth(600);
stg.setHeight(350);
stg.setScene(scene);
stg.initModality(Modality.APPLICATION_MODAL);
stg.show();
```

You can tweak the parameters of the drop-shadow to get your desired effect.
The doc related to parameters is as below :

[image]

Comment: almost like I wanted it. The shadow is working fine. My mistake was, that I put the shadow on the stackpane instead of the vbox.

But the padding (where the shadow is located) is not transparent. So the green window has a black shadow (good) with a white, non transparent border (not good) :-)

But thanks so far!

Comment: Ok, the reason for the white background is because of the Scene color and the root node color. By default javafx applies default color to the scene and root node. You need to explicitly set to transparent to make a complete transparent window. Updated  the code to set transparent colors to root node and scene. This should work for you.

Comment: Yeah, that workes. Seems to be a bug because an undecorated scene under linux has its default shadow around it. I am not sure if MacOS does that by default. Thanks and many greetings!